# How to find a directory disk usage over network? (Windows)

Tags: windows, scripting, powershell, local-area-network, disk-space-utilization

I have an external disk that is connected to a LAN network.
I want to find the disk usage of a directory on the disk from a script. I looked at power shell and SysInternals tools but couldn't find any solution. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Powershell makes it possible in the following way:

**Size in MB**

```
"Folder use {0:0,0.00} MB" -f (((Get-ChildItem -R C:\TEMP | measure-object length -Sum ).Sum / 1MB)
```

**Size in GB**

```
"Folder use {0:0,0.00} MB" -f (((Get-ChildItem -R C:\TEMP | measure-object length -Sum ).Sum / 1GB)
```

**Maybe in TB**

```
"Folder use {0:0,0.00} MB" -f (((Get-ChildItem -R C:\TEMP | measure-object length -Sum ).Sum / 1TB)
```

Comment: This works well, "Folder use 121.79 MB." You can also use 1KB in place of 1024.

Answer (score 1):

You could try any of the TreeSize type tools, for instance http://dev.carl-thomas.net/Utils/TreeSize/index.htm

Comment: Thanks for all the other posts. The answers where good but this one is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Microsoft Tool called Diruse.

> D:\Webmaster\cmd>diruse.exe C:\temp /M
>   /*
>
> ```
> Size (mb)  Files  Directory
>    501.75    138  SUB-TOTAL: C:\TEMP\Garbadge
>    501.75    138  TOTAL: C:\TEMP\Garbadge
> ```

You can find more about diruse [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786699(WS.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin's du will do the trick as well.

```
$ /bin/du 'C:\WINDOWS\system32' | sort -rn | head -20
1104392 C:\WINDOWS\system32
194127  C:\WINDOWS\system32/dllcache
61675   C:\WINDOWS\system32/spool
61284   C:\WINDOWS\system32/config
57336   C:\WINDOWS\system32/ReinstallBackups
54572   C:\WINDOWS\system32/ReinstallBackups/0020/DriverFiles
54572   C:\WINDOWS\system32/ReinstallBackups/0020
51952   C:\WINDOWS\system32/mui
51590   C:\WINDOWS\system32/wbem
48765   C:\WINDOWS\system32/spool/drivers
48573   C:\WINDOWS\system32/spool/drivers/w32x86
43233   C:\WINDOWS\system32/spool/drivers/w32x86/3
33102   C:\WINDOWS\system32/drivers
21610   C:\WINDOWS\system32/wbem/Repository
21609   C:\WINDOWS\system32/wbem/Repository/FS
12030   C:\WINDOWS\system32/spool/XPSEP
10244   C:\WINDOWS\system32/wbem/AutoRecover
9890    C:\WINDOWS\system32/CatRoot
9889    C:\WINDOWS\system32/CatRoot/{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}
9770    C:\WINDOWS\system32/CatRoot2
```

There you go: the twenty largest directory sizes (in K).